# Como transformar uma DLL criada em C# para VB6?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2013, vba

Eu criei uma DLL em C# bem básica, só para testar. Ficou assim:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace CriarDLL
{
[ComVisible(true), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual),
Guid("EB331808-BC1C-4B13-9ADC-E634E9102DF4")]
public interface ICalculator
{
    int AddNumbers(int x, int y);
    int SubNumbers(int x, int y);
    int MultNumbers(int x, int y);
    double DivNumbers(int x, int y);
}


[ComVisible(true), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None),
Guid("0BE3D996-63ED-4861-9310-05985C5FFA8E")]
public class Calculator : ICalculator
{
    //O construtor não pode conter parametros.
    public Calculator()
    {

    }

    public int AddNumbers(int x, int y)
    {
        return (x + y);
    }

    public int SubNumbers(int x, int y)
    {
        return (x - y);
    }

    public int MultNumbers(int x, int y)
    {
        return (x * y);
    }

    public double DivNumbers(int x, int y)
    {
        return (x / y);
    }
}
}
```

Fiz todos os processos de marcar `Register for COM interop`, marquei `Sign the assembly` e criei um `Strong Name Key`, transformei `Assembly Global` (GAC), Criei em serviços e componentes um Aplicativo COM+ (que mostra os métodos que estão na classe).

Então criei um outro projeto em C# (Windows Forms) para testar a DLL, quando fui adicionar uma referencia na aba COM, estava lá a DLL, mas quando cliquei em OK apareceu a seguinte mensagem:

> A reference to 'CriarDLL' could not be added.
>   The ActiveX type library 'local\CriarDLL.tlb' was exported from a .NET assembly and cannot be added as a reference.
>   Add a reference to the .NET assembly instead.

Alguém sabe se eu fiz algo de errado? Ou se está faltando algo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por algum motivo, o Visual Studio não deixa você adicionar uma .dll COM sabendo que esta .dll foi exposta a partir de um assembly .NET - ele força você a utilizar essa .dll como uma referência comum .NET.

Neste caso, para testar a sua .dll, sugiro você criar um código `vbscript`. Fiz um teste aqui e funcionou perfeitamente<sup>1</sup>.

Código vbscript:

```
' --- c:\temp\CriarDllCaller.vbs 
set objCriarDll = CreateObject("CriarDLL.Calculator")

WScript.Echo "Resultado Soma 2+2: " & objCriarDll.AddNumbers(2,2)
WScript.Echo "Resultado Subtração 10-5: " & objCriarDll.SubNumbers(10,5)
WScript.Echo "Resultado Multiplicação 5x5: " & objCriarDll.MultNumbers(5,5)
WScript.Echo "Resultado Divisao 20/4: " & objCriarDll.DivNumbers(20,4)
```

... e o comando para execução + resultado :

```
C:\temp>C:\windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe CriarDllCaller.vbs
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Versão 5.8
Copyright (C) 1996-2001 Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.

Resultado Soma 2+2: 4
Resultado Subtração 10-5: 5
Resultado Multiplicação 5x5: 25
Resultado Divisao 20/4: 5
```

1. Na verdade quebrei a cabeça no início; Tive que forçar a compilação do assembly e a execução do script ambos em 32-bits.

Fonte: http://jumbloid.blogspot.com.br/2009/12/making-net-dll-com-visible.html

Answer (score 1):

Segundo [uma resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614625/can-not-add-reference-a-com-in-com-client) publicada para uma pergunta semelhante no stackoverflow.com este erro ocorre pois ao invés de tentar adicionar uma referencia para o TBL, você deveria adicionar uma referencia a DLL!
Por favor tente e nos dê o feedback!

Comment: Se eu adicionar uma DLL pela aba Browser funciona normalmente, mas se eu tentar adicionar pela aba COM da aquele erro que eu postei.

Comment: Mas então o seu problema foi resolvido? Você consegue utilizar as funções da DLL desenvolvida em .NET na aplicação VB6?

Comment: Não, pensei que a sua resposta se referia ao Visual Studio, no VB6 eu não testei. Vou ter que testar em casa pra ter certeza.